# Why does Git merge the index file instead of completely overriding it when checking out a commit

Tags: git

This is the question about Git internals. I use low-level commands here and don't use branches.

#### Setup

```
echo f1 > f1.txt
echo f1 > f1.txt
git add .
git commit -m "first"
...cf178d5
```

Now I want to create a new commit with one file `f3.txt` using index and `write-tree` command:

```
$ rm f1.txt f2.txt
$ echo ‘f3 content’ > f3.txt
$ git add .
```

So currently the index file and the directory contains only new `f3.txt` file:

```
$ git ls-files -s
100644 [some hash] 0       f3.txt

$ ls
f3.txt
```

#### This what causes the weird behavior later

So I write the tree to the repository and update HEAD so with the new commit hash:

```
LATEST_TREE_HASH=$( git write-tree )
echo $LATEST_TREE_HASH > .git/HEAD
```

If I now run `git status` I get:

```
$ git status
Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

#### Question

If I now check out `first` commit with two files `f1.txt` and `f2.txt`:

```
$ git checkout cf178d5
A       f3.txt                    <--------------- why?
HEAD is now at a27a75a... initial commit
```

Git works fine but I believe it merges trees in the index instead of overriding. You can see it from the `git checkout` output that it treats `f3.txt` as added file and if I check the index file contents:

```
$ git ls-files -s
100644 [some hash] 0       f1.txt
100644 [some hash] 0       f2.txt
100644 [some hash] 0       f3.txt

$ ls 
f1.txt f2.txt f3.txt
```

It shows three files. What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: By overriding, the staged changes are lost. By merging, the user can choose to commit the changes or discard them. Losing unsaved changes is a disaster. Merging conflict in the index will always abort the checkout.

Comment: @ElpieKay, thanks, so what are you saying, it's not merging, it's something else here?

Comment: After *"Now I want to create a new commit..."* you run `rm f1.txt f2.txt` and several lines below, without doing any checkout, `ls` shows the files are still in the working tree. Are you sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: Also, `git commit -m "second commit"` is, in fact, the first commit. It contains only `f3.txt` because the other two files where removed from the working tree by `rm f1.txt f2.txt` (they were still in the index at that time) and then from the index by `git add .`

Comment: @axiac, I managed to simplify the setup. The problem is definitely with manual update of the HEAD. Can you take a look please now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: the question has changed enough to invalidate the previous response.

There's still a typo (`f1.txt` listed twice) and funky non-ASCII Unicode quote marks, but we can now see what is going wrong here:

> ```
> $ LATEST_TREE_HASH=$( git write-tree )
> $ echo $LATEST_TREE_HASH > .git/HEAD
> ```

This is a bit of a problem.  As [Mark Adelsberger noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842268/why-does-git-merge-the-index-file-instead-of-completely-overriding-it-when-check/45843275?noredirect=1#comment78647091_45843275) and your script says by using the word `TREE` here, `git write-tree` writes a *tree*, not a commit.

## Why this is a problem

What's in `.git/HEAD` is supposed to be exactly one of two things:

- a string of the form `ref: refs/heads/name`, where *`name`* is a valid branch name, or
- the hash ID of a *commit object*.

In turn, a branch name—a reference of the form `refs/heads/name`—*must* always point to a commit object, never to a blob, tree, or tag object.

This means that Git in general *assumes* that whatever comes out of `.git/HEAD`, it refers to a commit object.  By writing this tree hash into `.git/HEAD` you've violated this assumption.  However, to allow for "unborn branches", such as the state of an initial repository with no `master` yet, `HEAD` can contain the *name* of a branch that does not actually exist.

What happens next is, I think, not guaranteed.  The `git checkout` command assumes that if `HEAD` contains a valid hash, it contains a commit hash, and the only other allowed possibility is that `HEAD` contains the name of an orphan branch.  So we run `git checkout target_hash`, as in your example:

> ```
> git checkout cf178d5
> ```

#### Case 1: moving from commit to commit

Suppose `HEAD` contained a valid commit hash.  Let's call this the *old* hash, as distinguished from the *target* commit hash.  In this case, `git checkout` would:

- Compare (recursively as needed for sub-trees) the contents of the tree of *old* to the contents of the tree of *target*.<sup>1</sup>
- For each hash that must change, including being added or removed, check whether the index and/or work-tree file version in the current index and work-tree match those in *old*.
- If all match, update the index hashes and copy the new files to the work-tree (or remove the files from the work-tree and remove the index entry, if appropriate).
- Otherwise (some files don't match): complain and refuse the checkout.

Obviously `--force` disables the check, but [this is the basic process by which both staged and unstaged modifications are carried from one checkout to another when switching branches without being in a "clean" state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).  The process is described in all its gory detail in the [Two Tree Merge section of the `git read-tree` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html#_two_tree_merge).

#### Case 2: moving from orphan branch to commit

The other possibility allowed by the rules is that you are currently on an orphan branch.  In this case, there is no current commit.  Most likely, Git simply uses [the empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) *as if* it were the current commit.  It then follows the same rules for case 1, which is now allowed since it has a tree.

But this is, obviously, not guaranteed.  If Git were to use the current (valid) *tree* stored in `.git/HEAD` as the base tree, instead of the empty tree, and then proceed as for case 1, you'd see your two files get removed.  Follow all the sub-cases outlined in `git read-tree` with `$H` set to your existing tree, vs `$H` set to the empty tree.  (I admit to not having done so, but I think this is where the behavior comes from.  But see also the remark about case 3 in the read-tree documentation!)

---

<sup>1</sup>Git actually achieves this using a *temporary index*, stored in the `index.lock` file.  If all goes well, the temporary index is renamed to become the regular index, unlocking the index in the process.  If things go poorly, Git removes the temporary `index.lock` file, discarding the temporary index and unlocking the index.

## Original answer (to somewhat different question)

There's another set of funky non-ASCII quote marks that made cut and paste of your instructions fail, so that when I made the normal first commit I ended up with two files:

```
$ git commit -m "second commit"
[master (root-commit) b9c7e4b] second commit
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 f3.txt
 create mode 100644 f3.txtcontentecho
$ ls
f3.txt                  f3.txtcontentecho
$ git ls-files -s
100644 5927d85c2470d49403f56ce27afd8f74b1a42589 0       f3.txt
100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 0       f3.txtcontentecho
```

But note that my `ls` vs `ls-files -s` output differs enormously from yours at this point:

> So currently the index file and the directory contains only new f3.txt file:
>
> ```
> $ git ls-files -s
> 100644 [some hash] 0       f3.txt
>
> $ ls
> f1.txt f2.txt
> ```

It's not at all clear to me why you would have files `f1.txt` and `f2.txt` in your work-tree now; I don't.

Now we create a commit with `git commit-tree` and run `git checkout`:

```
$ INITIAL_COMMIT_HASH=$( \
>     echo 'initial commit' | git commit-tree $INITIAL_TREE_HASH )
$ git checkout $INITIAL_COMMIT_HASH
```

but what I get is very different:

```
Note: checking out 'cd1bc16160c8a2814cd94bc8397230ffe5a16c22'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at cd1bc16... initial commit
```

and everything reads as I would expect (files `f1.txt` and `f2.txt` are in the work-tree and the index; neither of the `f3` files are visible).  Running `git log --graph --all` shows the expected two (disconnected) commits (both are root commits, with no parents).

Comment: thanks, _It's not at all clear to me why you would have files f1.txt and f2.txt in your work-tree now; I don't._ - yeah, that's a typo, I get `f3.txt`. Let me go through the code again, maybe I missed something, I was copying it

Comment: I managed to simplify the setup. The problem is definitely with manual update of the `HEAD`. Can you take a look please now?

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi - `git write-tree` creates a `TREE`, not a `COMMIT`.  After you remove the first two files and create the 3rd file, you aren't committing anything (according to the steps you've written in the current version of your question); so the contents of the index are "changes staged for commit", the fact that you have a random tree object in the database notwithstanding.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, thanks, I know that `write-tree` creates a tree, not a commit. Actually if I run `git status` after I update the `HEAD`, I can see the following `Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit, working directory clean`. I added these details to the question. So git doesn't report any changes staged for commit. This is because git compares the index file with the tree in `INDEX` and since I updated the INDEX they are the same

Comment: thanks, I've accepted your answer. It seems that your main point is that putting a tree hash into the HEAD will lead to an undefined behavior, correct? The two cases you outlined are not really relevant to my case, correct? However, I'm very curios to understand the CASE1. I have some questions regarding the  operations, do you know if there's a thread that shows these operations on stackoverflow? If not, I will probably create a new question. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Yes, Git is very insistent on having `HEAD` name a valid commit (or nothing at all), so much so that some operations that update `refs/heads/*` names refuse to do so if you attempt to point them to a tag (I tried this as an experiment once). For the read-tree "two tree merge" case, follow the links (the answer text has embedded links).